# Falha oculta a geração de array

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte método de **login** em uma **Classe** **php**:

```
public function loginMembro( $_usuario, $_senha ) {

        $membro = null;

        $string = "SELECT idMembro, nome, apelido, bloqueado, usuario, senha
                   FROM membros
                   WHERE usuario ='" . $_usuario . "' AND senha ='" . $_senha . "' ";

        $registros = $this->conexao->query( $string );
        $quantasLinhas = $registros->num_rows;

        if ( $quantasLinhas > 0 ) {

            list( $idMembro, $nomeMembro, $apelido, $bloqueado, $usuario, $senha ) = $registros->fetch_row();

            $membro[ "idMembro" ] = $idMembro;
            $membro[ "nomeMembro" ] = $nomeMembro;
            $membro[ "apelido" ] = $apelido;
            $membro[ "bloqueado" ] = $bloqueado;
            $membro[ "usuario" ] = $usuario;
            $membro[ "senha" ] = $senha;

        }

        return $membro;

    }
```

No servidor da UOL Host, funciona normal. Porém, localmente, o array NÃO está sendo gerado.

Antes do return $membro, adicionei um

```
pring_r($membro);
```

mas não exibe nada e nem dá erro no inspector

Estou usando **Ajax**:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $("#logar").on("click", function () {

        usuario = $("#usuario").val();
        senha = $("#senha").val();

        if (usuario == "") {
            $(".resposta").html("Preencha usuário!");
            return false;
        }
        if (senha == "") {
            $(".resposta").html("Preencha senha!");
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "_scripts/_php/_validacoes/acesso.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                usuario: usuario,
                senha: senha
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result[1]["bloqueado"] == "bloqueado")
                    $(".resposta").html("Membro bloqueado!");
                else if (result[0] == "inexistente")
                    $(".resposta").html(result[1]);
                else
                    window.location = "celula.php";
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Obs.: Localmente rodei a **string** no **MySQL** e deu retorno.
Onde será que estou errando?

O **HTML**

```
<div class="logon">
    <div class="logos">
        <img src="_imgs/gceu.png"/>
    </div>
    <h2>Acessar</h2>
    <div class="pseudo">
        <img src="_imgs/user.png"/>
        <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" placeholder="Usuário"/>
    </div>
    <div class="pseudo">
        <img src="_imgs/pass.png"/>
        <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" placeholder="Senha"/>
    </div>
    <div class="lembra">
        <a href="recuperaSenha.php?recuperar">Esqueceu a senha?</a>
    </div>
    <button id="logar">LOGIN</button>
    <div class="resposta"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Se retornou `null`, então não entrou na condição que define `$membro`, logo `$quantasLinhas` deve ser zero. Veja no debug se o valor realmente está chegando como zero.

Comment: sim, o $registros->num_rows diz que é 0. Porém, se pegarmos a $string e lançarmos diretamente no MySQL está dando 1 retorno

Comment: E qual é o valor de string? Ela gerada no PHP, `var_dump($string)` antes de executar a query

Comment: SELECT idMembro, nome, apelido, bloqueado, usuario, senha
       FROM membros
       WHERE usuario ='caca' AND senha ='74b87337454200d4d33f80c4663dc5e5'

Comment: javaScript e JQuery funcionam, normalmente.

Comment: Então veja se está conectado no mesmo banco. Se a mesma SQL produz diferentes resultados, devem estar em bancos distintos.